# Could not use explicit wait in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to use explicit wait in my script but it didn't work. I got an error as following. What is the problem. I referenced this link. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

error:

```
"Message: javascript error: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver function O(a){this._c=[],this._a=void 0,this._s=0,this._d=!1,this._v=void 0,this._h=0,this._n=!1}   (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)"
```

Code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@cdl='xxxx']//*[text()='xxxx']")))
element.click()
```

Comment: Check if your ChromeDriver is also version 78.

Comment: yes, it is 78 :( still now working